# Adding attributes to user entity via. install script

Tags: php, xml, magento

I recently got a new internship, where i have to programme with Magento, which i have never tried before. A part of my current assignment is to add some extra attributes to our customer entity, which will then show in the back-end.

At this point i have managed to add an attribute, which is a textfield in the back-end, but what i really want to do, is to add a select box with predefined options. Whenever i try to do that, my Magento goes corrupt, to the point where i have to reinstall the whole thing. I am running my head against the wall at the moment.

I am doing this via. an install script, from a module i created.

Below i have pasted in my install script, but if you need to see more code, please let me know.

**mysql4-install-0.1.0.php:**

```
<?php 

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'skintype', array(
    'input'         => 'select',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'option'        => array(
                                'optionone' => array('zero' => array(0 => 'normal hud')),
                                'optiontwo' => array('one' => array(1 => 'tør hud')),
                                'optionthree' => array('two' => array(2 => 'fedtet hud')),
                                'optionfour' => array('three' => array(3 => 'kombineret hud')),
                                'optionfive' => array('four' => array(4 => 'sensibel hud'))
                            ),  
    'default'       => array('optionone'),
    'label'         => 'Skintype',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
));

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'skintype');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));
$oAttribute->save();

$setup->endSetup();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight changes would be all that is required

Use LIke

`'option'     => array (
        'value' => array(
            '0'=>array(0=>'Small'),
            '1'=>array(0=>'Medium'),
            '2'=>array(0=>'Large'),
        )
    ),`

Comment: I will give it a shot later today. :) 

If you dont mind me asking, if i already created an attribute called "hairtype", how would i, say, update it from a textfield to a select box?

Comment: Sorry but updating can't be done programmatically. Can be done changing fields in database. But its complicated. Would prefer delete the attribute create a new one

Comment: How should one delete it? could it be done via an update or install script? :)

Comment: How does one delete the attribute programmatically ?